# Unable to update picklist value using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-components

When I click a button in LWC to update a picklist value, I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDk93.jpg. How can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template if:true={opportunities.data}>
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={opportunities.data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            >
           </lightning-datatable>
       </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**APEX**

```
  public with sharing class OpportunityController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static void closeOpportunity(Id closeId){
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Id = closeId);
            opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';
            List<Opportunity> res = new List<Opportunity>();
            res.add(opp);
            insert res;
        }
}
```

**JS**

```
        import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
        import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
        import AMOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Amount';
        import closeOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.closeOpportunity';
        import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
        
        const COLUMNS = [
            {
              label: "Edit",
              type: "button",
              typeAttributes: {
                  label: "Edit",
                  name: "editOpportunity",
                  variant: "brand"
              }
          }
        ];
        
        export default class MiscRecord extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
            columns = COLUMNS;
//Used another Apex call to fetch details into the opportunities variable.

                handleRowAction(event) {
                  if (event.detail.action.name === "editOpportunity") {
                    closeOpportunity(closeId= event.detail.row.Id).then(data=>{
                      this.error = null;
                    } 
                    ).catch(error =>{
                      this.error = error;
                    }
                    )
                }
              }
        }
```

Comment: when you open developer tools, is there showing an error?
also, could you add the code for the picklist?

Comment: @EliveltonWalter no error in developer tools. the picklist is a default in-built one.

Comment: you cannot perform DML in cacheable = true methods. And you have to pass parameter from js like this closeId : event.detail.row.Id

Comment: @KaranSharma making these two changes removes the error message, but the object does not get updated, old value being displayed

Comment: If you get data from wire method then you have to use refreshApex to update the data in datatable when your operation in done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you cannot perform dml operation in

> @`AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` methods

so change it to

> @AuraEnabled

And calling of your method will look like

```
closeOpportunity(closeId:event.detail.row.Id).then(data=>{
                      this.error = null;
                    }
```

Comment: {closeId:event.detail.row.Id}